# Find specific string in a div and delete its html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a way using javascript to find a specific string and delete its' html element. 
For example, I have this following html code:

```
<div class="summary">
List of texts:
  <ul>
   <li>Text 0</li>
   <li>Text 1</li>
   <li>Text 2</li>
   <li>Text 3</li> 
   <li>Text 4</li>
   <li>Text 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and I want to hide "Text 2", first I want to find this string and then hide it. 
what I've tried is using html().replace but it hides only the text not the element.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLa3dkdd/2/)

Comment: jquery is also valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is pretty close. Here's an updated version removing the element from the DOM.

```
$('.summary li').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.text() === 'Text 2') {
       $this.remove();
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLa3dkdd/3/

Answer (score 7):

In jQuery there is [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
$('.summary li:contains(Text 2)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summary">
List of texts:
  <ul>
   <li>Text 0</li>
   <li>Text 1</li>
   <li>Text 2</li>
   <li>Text 3</li> 
   <li>Text 4</li>
   <li>Text 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this answer. Very simple.

Comment: More efficient than mine! GJ :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterrate over li elements, check if the text content is the searched value, then hide or remove the element.

```
 $(function() {
  $('.summary li').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.text() === 'Text 2'){$this.hide();}
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery you can do it like that :

```
$('.summary ul').children().each(function () {
    if($(this).text() == searchedValue) {
        $(this).hide(); 
    }
})
```

Comment: I commented to say that what Alexander did was to best way to do the trick. You are all right for the improvement. I'll edit this. Thank you for the advice